# repository pattern x non matching business object

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, ddd-repositories

I understand well why and how to use a repository and the same applies to query objects, they all seem simple to understand as long as you need, for instance, objects that mirror exactly what is in the database.

But I can't seem to get my head around where exactly to fit the objects for a very specific structure I'm building right now.

I have products and categories, and they all have their repository.

My categories exist within a self-referencing parent-child structure.

I have products that belong to a category that don't have child categories.

Now I need to pull this data to put together a menu which will be like this:

Data:

- Kitchen (category)

  - Cutlery (category)

    - Knives (category)

      - 3-piece knives set (product)
    - Spoons (category)

      - 3-piece spoons set (product)
    - Appliances

      - Coffee-Making-Machines (category)

        - Nespresso Machine (product)
        - Espresso Machine (product
      - Blenders (category)

        - Smoothie Blender (product)

Then I need a menu, which will be like this:

- Kitchen (this will be a link to see all its child categories)

  - 3-piece knives set (this will a link directly to the product page)
  - Nespresso Machine
  - Smoothie Blender
- Another Category

  - Another product 1
  - Another product 2
  - Another product 3

This will be a list of all top level categories in which the vendor has products in our marketplace, with a randomly selected list of products that are under that top level category regardless of the category level.

All fine, I got all that working.
Now I'm just trying to understand where does this kind of structure fit in an architecture which has repositories that basically contain one object per table.

How do I match my repositories, which mirrors raw data into a totally different business object?

If someone could point me to a good article that tackle this problem, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository pattern emerges in the context of DDD, and the best book to read on that would be the original [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

One of the things that Evans keeps saying over and over is that all of the concepts of the domain must be explicit.

What does your menu represent? 
Does it have a name in the domain?

Lets say it does, and it is the concept of "weekly promoted products", then you could make this concept explicit - and introduce a separate class for that, with a separate repository, that could read data from products table, and from categories table to come up with the list of promoted products.

Please note that according to Evans our domain and persistence models do not have to match, and we don't need to have a repository per domain object (specifically, we should **only** have repositories for aggregate roots, and references all other entities should be obtained by traversing the association from the aggregate root)

Alternatively, in a design, somewhat departed from DDD, you could place the selection of those promoted products in the product repository, pre-load the categories and just have a TopCategory calculation property on a product

Please note, that if the new entity "promoted products" is purely virtual, and you are **only** planning to do read operations, without mutating its state, then it makes a lot of sense to apply [Command Query Responsibility Seggregation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), and have a separate read model for "promoted products" outside of your main domain model.

Comment: That makes sense. I was reading something along the lines of having objects grouped as an aggregate with an aggregate root.
By your answer I'm being able to deduct that it's not wrong to have a repository that only serves as a database reader, is that correct?
I think the root cause of my wrong mindset was thinking of repositories as places where recording data in the database was kind of mandatory.

Comment: @JBourne, exactly, there is no constraint that repositories must do both read and write operations, but if you are doing only read, check out CQRS https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html
To reassure you, let me quote Evans, the author of DDD on repositories: "REPOSITORIES can implement a variety of queries that select objects based on whatever criteria the client requires. They can also return summary information, such as a count of how many instances
meet some criteria. They can even return summary calculations, such as the total across all matching objects of some numerical attribute"